# An algorithm to checking a list without having the whole list items

Tags: algorithm, list, hash, cryptography, compression

how can I check a huge list that a special element is exists in that or not without having whole list?
for example we have a list of hexadecimal numbers and then I want to send it over network I will need an alternative related thing to send it over net and receiver just check is some items included in the list without need for knowing whole items and read them or sort of the list.

I think we can use a hash of whole list and break that for searching the element or some compression algorithm to minimize the list and check for that element.

it better for security reasons unable the reading whole data and just ability to checking item existence and have least size for  transferring coast and have most existence checking speed for performance reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do that, if each item has an unique ID, then you can use a hashList.
A hashList is a  list that each item is indexed by a key.

The principle is simple, hashList will calculate the hash of the key, then it will use that hash to determine the memory address on which the object will be saved.

So, if you want to know if list contain an element, you will only need O(1) using the key.

Comment: difficulty is there is not unique id. items are random long numbers (private keys of an asymmetric encryption algorithm) and the only unique property is just the hexadecimal key number and its sha256 hash.

Answer (score 0):

Bloom filters are very close solution but it’s not accurate on non-existence probably returns but while not exists but are accurate for existence.

I found hyperloglog and it's the answer I was looking for